# Can't stop images from going beyond my screen size

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a background using three images, as shown in the code below. As usual I used `display: flex` and `flex: 1` to organize them and so that they used all the available space and have the same size.

They do have the same size, but they are going beyond my screen size and I can't find a solution for that. I tried to use `max-width`, `flex-grow` and `flex-basis` but nothing worked so far. And after inspecting the page in my browser (I'm using chrome) it shows that the parent div as the same size as the screen but the last image goes beyond the parent div length.

I have the folowing code:

```
<div class="pagina-registar">
  <img src="./images/scooter.jfif" class="painel" />
  <img src="./images/globo.jfif" class="painel" />
  <img src="./images/r2d2.jfif" class="painel" />
</div>

<style>
.pagina-registar {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.painel {
  flex: 1;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying a max-width on the images themselves, that way they can't extend past their allowed space.

```
.pagina-registar {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.painel {
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 33.33%;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. But my fear is that using the 33.33% might become a problem later when making sure everything is responsive and adaptive to the screen size. What do you think?

Comment: @TuBzz For responsive screen sizes you can use [media queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile) to adjust the style and allowed sizing based on the screen size.

Answer (score 0):

Change `flex: 1;` to `flex: auto;`

[image]

Comment: Sorry I haven't mencioned it in my original question, but I tried that already and it did not work

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your images in a `<div>`

```css
.d1, .d2 {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

.d1 img, .d2 img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.d2>* {
  flex: 1 1 0;
}
```

```html
<p>relative image widths retained</p>
<div class="d1">
  <div><img src="http://picsum.photos/400/250"></div>
  <div><img src="http://picsum.photos/500/250"></div>
  <div><img src="http://picsum.photos/600/250"></div>
</div>

<p>image widths ignored</p>
<div class="d2">
  <div><img src="http://picsum.photos/400/250"></div>
  <div><img src="http://picsum.photos/500/250"></div>
  <div><img src="http://picsum.photos/600/250"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried that and it did not work for me, in fact it got worst because when i did it that way the height was also bigger then the screen, not only the width